# How to switch from first github account to second?

Tags: git, ssh

I worked on Project A with the git credentials(*`user.name= venkat` and `user.email=venkat@gmail.com`*) which is completed successfully.

And I started my new Project B.
For this I created my login credentials(*`user.name= venkat-yahoo` and `user.email=venkat@yahoo.com`*) and added ssh with new credentials.
The ssh generated is fine with new email but when I did my first push to GitHub, it is pushed with my old user.email / name.

I checked with credentials, it resulted with old credentials as:

```
myvenkat@myvm:~/Desktop/project/ProjectB/projectB-master$ git config --list
user.name= venkat
user.email=venkat@gmail.com
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=git@github.com:xxxxx/ProjectB.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

Leave the first push done from old credentials, now I want to push everything from new credentials. How it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your local config in order to use your new name/email

```
git config user.name venkat-yahoo
git config user.email venkat@yahoo.com
git config -l
```

This has nothing to do with the ssh you will be using for pushing to GitHub though.

For this, you need to setup a `~/.ssh/config` file in order to instruct git to use the right ssh key.

```
Host githubyahoo github
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile "~/.ssh/github_yahoo_rsa"
```

And change the remote repo url:

```
git remote set-url origin githubyahoo:<user>/<repo>
```

Again, `user.name` and `user.email` have nothing to do with GitHub authentication (which would use your new ssh key).
They have to do with author/commit identity associated with your commits.
That username is visible on each commits, which is maybe what you meant by "it is pushed with my old user.email / name."

But you can very well push commits done as X with a GitHub account Y (referenced by an ssh key): both (commit author and GitHub account) are very different concepts.